# Prawn encoding not correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, utf-8, prawn

I have problems runnig this code with Prawn:

```
require 'prawn'
Prawn::Document.generate "example.pdf" do |pdf|
   pdf.text_box "W\xF6rth".force_encoding('UTF-8'), :at => [200,720], :size => 32
end
```

somehow i get this error:

```
`rescue in normalize_encoding': Arguments to text methods must be UTF-8
   encoded(Prawn::Errors::IncompatibleStringEncoding)
```

But when i try this code, it works:

```
pdf.text_box "Wörth".force_encoding('UTF-8')
```

What do i wrong? How can i also fix my first example with the `\xF6` in the string? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"W\xF6rth"` is not a valid UTF-8 sequence.

```
"W\xF6rth".valid_encoding?
=> false
```

The maximum one-byte character code in UTF-8 is 0x7F, after that you need to start encoding with two bytes.

```
"Wörth".bytes.map { |b| b.to_s(16) }
=> ["57", "c3", "b6", "72", "74", "68"]
           ^^----^^ <-- Two bytes representing UTF-8 "ö"
```

I think you're trying to convert ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8.
In ISO-8859-1 "ö" is 0xF6.

This is what should work in your case:

```
"W\xf6rth".force_encoding('iso-8859-1').encode('utf-8')
=> "Wörth"
```

I.e.

```
pdf.text_box "W\xF6rth".force_encoding('iso-8859-1').encode('utf-8'), ...
```

References:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8